# Certificates: OID reference for extended key usages

Tags: certificate, x509certificate

Is there a reference that maps OIDs to terms used in Microsoft documentation like "Server Authentication" or "Secure Email"?

```
Server Authentication:    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
Client Authentication:    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
Secure Email:             1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4
Data Encipherment:        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4
Key Encipherment:         ?
Digital Signature:  ?
```

I am using these OIDs to generate test certificates with makecert.exe.

Answer (score 3):

There is a support document in the Microsoft knowledge base: https://web.archive.org/web/20180608195005/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/287547/object-ids-associated-with-microsoft-cryptography

As MSFT keeps flipping URLs and dropping information here is a scrap:

```
Microsoft OID...................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311

Authenticode....................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2
     Software Publishing (with associated encoders/decoders)
        SPC_INDIRECT_DATA_OBJID                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.4
        SPC_STATEMENT_TYPE_OBJID                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.11
        SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO_OBJID                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.12
        SPC_PE_IMAGE_DATA_OBJID                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.15
        SPC_SP_AGENCY_INFO_OBJID                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.10
        SPC_MINIMAL_CRITERIA_OBJID              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.26
        SPC_FINANCIAL_CRITERIA_OBJID            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.27
        SPC_LINK_OBJID                          1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.28
        SPC_HASH_INFO_OBJID                     1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.29
        SPC_SIPINFO_OBJID                       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.30
     
     Software Publishing (with NO associated encoders/decoders)
        SPC_CERT_EXTENSIONS_OBJID               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.14
        SPC_RAW_FILE_DATA_OBJID                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.18
        SPC_STRUCTURED_STORAGE_DATA_OBJID       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.19
        SPC_JAVA_CLASS_DATA_OBJID               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.20
        SPC_INDIVIDUAL_SP_KEY_PURPOSE_OBJID     1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.21
        SPC_COMMERCIAL_SP_KEY_PURPOSE_OBJID     1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.22
        SPC_CAB_DATA_OBJID                      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.25
        SPC_GLUE_RDN_OBJID                      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.25  
     
     CTL for Software Publishers Trusted CAs    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2
     (sub-subtree is defined for Software Publishing trusted CAs)
        szOID_TRUSTED_CODESIGNING_CA_LIST       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.1
        szOID_TRUSTED_CLIENT_AUTH_CA_LIST       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.2
        szOID_TRUSTED_SERVER_AUTH_CA_LIST       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.3

Time Stamping...................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.3
(with Associated encoder/decoders)
        SPC_TIME_STAMP_REQUEST_OBJID            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.3.2.1

Permissions.....................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.4

Crypto 2.0......................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10
     PKCS #7 ContentType Object Identifier for Certificate Trust List (CTL)
        szOID_CTL                               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.1
     Sorted CTL Extension
        szOID_SORTED_CTL                        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.1.1
     
     Next Update Location extension or attribute. Value is an encoded GeneralNames
        szOID_NEXT_UPDATE_LOCATION              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.2
     
     Enhanced Key Usage (Purpose)
        Signer of CTLs
        szOID_KP_CTL_USAGE_SIGNING              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.1
     
        Signer of TimeStamps
        szOID_KP_TIME_STAMP_SIGNING             1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.2
     
     Can use strong encryption in export environment
        szOID_SERVER_GATED_CRYPTO               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.3
        szOID_SERIALIZED                        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.3.1
     
     Can use encrypted file systems (EFS)
        szOID_EFS_CRYPTO                        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4
        szOID_EFS_RECOVERY                      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4.1
     
     Can use Windows Hardware Compatible (WHQL)
        szOID_WHQL_CRYPTO                       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.5
     
     Signed by the NT5 build lab
        szOID_NT5_CRYPTO                        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.6
     
     Signed by and OEM of WHQL
        szOID_OEM_WHQL_CRYPTO                   1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.7
     
     Signed by the Embedded NT
        szOID_EMBEDDED_NT_CRYPTO                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.8
     
     Signer of a CTL containing trusted roots
        szOID_ROOT_LIST_SIGNER                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.9
     
     Can sign cross-cert and subordinate CA requests with qualified 
     subordination (name constraints, policy mapping, etc.)
        szOID_KP_QUALIFIED_SUBORDINATION        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.10
     
     Can be used to encrypt/recover escrowed keys
        szOID_KP_KEY_RECOVERY                   1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.11
     
     Signer of documents
        szOID_KP_DOCUMENT_SIGNING               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.12
     
     Microsoft Attribute Object Identifiers
        szOID_YESNO_TRUST_ATTR                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.4.1
     
     Microsoft Music
        szOID_DRM                               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.5.1
     
     Microsoft DRM EKU
        szOID_DRM_INDIVIDUALIZATION             1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.5.2
     
     Microsoft Licenses
        szOID_LICENSES                          1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.6.1
        szOID_LICENSE_SERVER                    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.6.2
     
     Microsoft CERT_RDN attribute Object Identifiers
        szOID_MICROSOFT_RDN_PREFIX              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.7
     Special RDN containing the KEY_ID. Its value type is CERT_RDN_OCTET_STRING.
        szOID_KEYID_RDN                         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.7.1
     
     Microsoft extension in a CTL to add or remove the certificates. The
     extension type is an INTEGER. 0 =&amp;gt; add certificate, 1 =&amp;gt; remove certificate
        szOID_REMOVE_CERTIFICATE                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.8.1
     
     Microsoft certificate extension containing cross certificate distribution
     points. ASN.1 encoded as follows:
         CrossCertDistPoints ::= SEQUENCE {
             syncDeltaTime               INTEGER (0..4294967295) OPTIONAL,
             crossCertDistPointNames     CrossCertDistPointNames
         } --#public--
              CrossCertDistPointNames ::= SEQUENCE OF GeneralNames
              
        szOID_CROSS_CERT_DIST_POINTS            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.9.1
     
     
     Microsoft CMC OIDs                         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.10
     
     Similar to szOID_CMC_ADD_EXTENSIONS. Attributes replaces Extensions.
        szOID_CMC_ADD_ATTRIBUTES                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.10.1
     
     Microsoft certificate property OIDs        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.11
     The OID component following the prefix contains the PROP_ID (decimal)
        szOID_CERT_PROP_ID_PREFIX               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.11.
     
     CryptUI                                    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.12
        szOID_ANY_APPLICATION_POLICY            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.12.1

Catalog.........................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12
        szOID_CATALOG_LIST                      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12.1.1
        szOID_CATALOG_LIST_MEMBER               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12.1.2
        CAT_NAMEVALUE_OBJID                     1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12.2.1
        CAT_MEMBERINFO_OBJID                    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12.2.2
     
Microsoft PKCS10 OIDs...........................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13
        szOID_RENEWAL_CERTIFICATE               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.1
        szOID_ENROLLMENT_NAME_VALUE_PAIR        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.2.1
        szOID_ENROLLMENT_CSP_PROVIDER           1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.2.2

Microsoft Java..................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.15

Microsoft Outlook/Exchange......................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.16
          Outlook Express                       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.16.4
          Used by OL/OLEXP to identify which certificate signed the PKCS # 7 message

Microsoft PKCS12 attributes.....................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17
        szOID_LOCAL_MACHINE_KEYSET              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.1

Microsoft Hydra.................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.18

Microsoft ISPU Test.............................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.19

Microsoft Enrollment Infrastructure..............1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20
        szOID_AUTO_ENROLL_CTL_USAGE             1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.1
     Extension contain certificate type
        szOID_ENROLL_CERTTYPE_EXTENSION         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2
        szOID_ENROLLMENT_AGENT                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.1
        szOID_KP_SMARTCARD_LOGON                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2
        szOID_NT_PRINCIPAL_NAME                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3
        szOID_CERT_MANIFOLD                     1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.3

Microsoft CertSrv Infrastructure.................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21
     CertSrv (with associated encoders/decoders)
        szOID_CERTSRV_CA_VERSION                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.1

Microsoft Directory Service.....................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.25
        szOID_NTDS_REPLICATION                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.25.1

IIS.............................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.30

Windows updates and service packs...............1.3.6.1.4.1.311.31
        szOID_PRODUCT_UPDATE                    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.31.1

Fonts...........................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.40

Microsoft Licensing and Registration............1.3.6.1.4.1.311.41

Microsoft Corporate PKI (ITG)...................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.42

CAPICOM.........................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88
        szOID_CAPICOM                           1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88      Reserved for CAPICOM.
        szOID_CAPICOM_VERSION                   1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.1    CAPICOM version
        szOID_CAPICOM_ATTRIBUTE                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2    CAPICOM attribute
        szOID_CAPICOM_DOCUMENT_NAME             1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2.1  Document type attribute
        szOID_CAPICOM_DOCUMENT_DESCRIPTION      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2.2  Document description attribute
        szOID_CAPICOM_ENCRYPTED_DATA            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.3    CAPICOM encrypted data message.
        szOID_CAPICOM_ENCRYPTED_CONTENT         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.3.1  CAPICOM content of encrypted data.
Microsoft OID...................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311

Authenticode....................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2
     Software Publishing (with associated encoders/decoders)
        SPC_INDIRECT_DATA_OBJID                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.4
        SPC_STATEMENT_TYPE_OBJID                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.11
        SPC_SP_OPUS_INFO_OBJID                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.12
        SPC_PE_IMAGE_DATA_OBJID                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.15
        SPC_SP_AGENCY_INFO_OBJID                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.10
        SPC_MINIMAL_CRITERIA_OBJID              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.26
        SPC_FINANCIAL_CRITERIA_OBJID            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.27
        SPC_LINK_OBJID                          1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.28
        SPC_HASH_INFO_OBJID                     1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.29
        SPC_SIPINFO_OBJID                       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.30

     Software Publishing (with NO associated encoders/decoders)
        SPC_CERT_EXTENSIONS_OBJID               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.14
        SPC_RAW_FILE_DATA_OBJID                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.18
        SPC_STRUCTURED_STORAGE_DATA_OBJID       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.19
        SPC_JAVA_CLASS_DATA_OBJID               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.20
        SPC_INDIVIDUAL_SP_KEY_PURPOSE_OBJID     1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.21
        SPC_COMMERCIAL_SP_KEY_PURPOSE_OBJID     1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.22
        SPC_CAB_DATA_OBJID                      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.25
        SPC_GLUE_RDN_OBJID                      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.25

     CTL for Software Publishers Trusted CAs    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2
     (sub-subtree is defined for Software Publishing trusted CAs)
        szOID_TRUSTED_CODESIGNING_CA_LIST       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.1
        szOID_TRUSTED_CLIENT_AUTH_CA_LIST       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.2
        szOID_TRUSTED_SERVER_AUTH_CA_LIST       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.3

Time Stamping...................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.3
(with Associated encoder/decoders)
        SPC_TIME_STAMP_REQUEST_OBJID            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.3.2.1

Permissions.....................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.4

Crypto 2.0......................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10
     PKCS #7 ContentType Object Identifier for Certificate Trust List (CTL)
        szOID_CTL                               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.1
     Sorted CTL Extension
        szOID_SORTED_CTL                        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.1.1

     Next Update Location extension or attribute. Value is an encoded GeneralNames
        szOID_NEXT_UPDATE_LOCATION              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.2

     Enhanced Key Usage (Purpose)
        Signer of CTLs
        szOID_KP_CTL_USAGE_SIGNING              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.1

        Signer of TimeStamps
        szOID_KP_TIME_STAMP_SIGNING             1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.2

     Can use strong encryption in export environment
        szOID_SERVER_GATED_CRYPTO               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.3
        szOID_SERIALIZED                        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.3.1

     Can use encrypted file systems (EFS)
        szOID_EFS_CRYPTO                        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4
        szOID_EFS_RECOVERY                      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4.1

     Can use Windows Hardware Compatible (WHQL)
        szOID_WHQL_CRYPTO                       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.5

     Signed by the NT5 build lab
        szOID_NT5_CRYPTO                        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.6

     Signed by and OEM of WHQL
        szOID_OEM_WHQL_CRYPTO                   1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.7

     Signed by the Embedded NT
        szOID_EMBEDDED_NT_CRYPTO                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.8

     Signer of a CTL containing trusted roots
        szOID_ROOT_LIST_SIGNER                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.9

     Can sign cross-cert and subordinate CA requests with qualified
     subordination (name constraints, policy mapping, etc.)
        szOID_KP_QUALIFIED_SUBORDINATION        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.10

     Can be used to encrypt/recover escrowed keys
        szOID_KP_KEY_RECOVERY                   1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.11

     Signer of documents
        szOID_KP_DOCUMENT_SIGNING               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.12

     Limits the valid lifetime of the signature to the lifetime of the certificate.
        szOID_KP_LIFETIME_SIGNING               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13
        szOID_KP_MOBILE_DEVICE_SOFTWARE         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.14

     Microsoft Attribute Object Identifiers
        szOID_YESNO_TRUST_ATTR                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.4.1

     Microsoft Music
        szOID_DRM                               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.5.1

     Microsoft DRM EKU
        szOID_DRM_INDIVIDUALIZATION             1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.5.2

     Microsoft Licenses
        szOID_LICENSES                          1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.6.1
        szOID_LICENSE_SERVER                    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.6.2

     Microsoft CERT_RDN attribute Object Identifiers
        szOID_MICROSOFT_RDN_PREFIX              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.7
     Special RDN containing the KEY_ID. Its value type is CERT_RDN_OCTET_STRING.
        szOID_KEYID_RDN                         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.7.1

     Microsoft extension in a CTL to add or remove the certificates. The
     extension type is an INTEGER. 0 => add certificate, 1 => remove certificate
        szOID_REMOVE_CERTIFICATE                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.8.1

     Microsoft certificate extension containing cross certificate distribution
     points. ASN.1 encoded as follows:
         CrossCertDistPoints ::= SEQUENCE {
             syncDeltaTime               INTEGER (0..4294967295) OPTIONAL,
             crossCertDistPointNames     CrossCertDistPointNames
         } --#public--
              CrossCertDistPointNames ::= SEQUENCE OF GeneralNames

        szOID_CROSS_CERT_DIST_POINTS            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.9.1


     Microsoft CMC OIDs                         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.10

     Similar to szOID_CMC_ADD_EXTENSIONS. Attributes replaces Extensions.
        szOID_CMC_ADD_ATTRIBUTES                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.10.1

     Microsoft certificate property OIDs        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.11
     The OID component following the prefix contains the PROP_ID (decimal)
        szOID_CERT_PROP_ID_PREFIX               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.11.

     CryptUI                                    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.12
        szOID_ANY_APPLICATION_POLICY            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.12.1

Catalog.........................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12
        szOID_CATALOG_LIST                      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12.1.1
        szOID_CATALOG_LIST_MEMBER               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12.1.2
        CAT_NAMEVALUE_OBJID                     1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12.2.1
        CAT_MEMBERINFO_OBJID                    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.12.2.2

Microsoft PKCS10 OIDs...........................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13
        szOID_RENEWAL_CERTIFICATE               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.1
        szOID_ENROLLMENT_NAME_VALUE_PAIR        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.2.1
        szOID_ENROLLMENT_CSP_PROVIDER           1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.2.2
        szOID_OS_VERSION                        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.2.3

Microsoft Java..................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.15

Microsoft Outlook/Exchange......................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.16
      Used by OL/OLEXP to identify which certificate signed the PKCS # 7 message
        szOID_MICROSOFT_Encryption_Key_Preference  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.16.4

Microsoft PKCS12 attributes.....................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17
        szOID_LOCAL_MACHINE_KEYSET              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.1

Microsoft Hydra.................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.18
     License Info root
        szOID_PKIX_LICENSE_INFO                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.18.1

     Manufacturer value
        szOID_PKIX_MANUFACTURER                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.18.2

     Manufacturer Specfic Data
        szOID_PKIX_MANUFACTURER_MS_SPECIFIC     1.3.6.1.4.1.311.18.3

     OID for Certificate Version Stamp
        szOID_PKIX_HYDRA_CERT_VERSION           1.3.6.1.4.1.311.18.4

     OID for License Server to identify licensed product.
        szOID_PKIX_LICENSED_PRODUCT_INFO        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.18.5

     OID for License Server specific info.
        szOID_PKIX_MS_LICENSE_SERVER_INFO       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.18.6

     Extension OID reserved for product policy module - only one is allowed.
        szOID_PKIS_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_OID         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.18.7
        szOID_PKIS_TLSERVER_SPK_OID             1.3.6.1.4.1.311.18.8

Microsoft ISPU Test.............................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.19

Microsoft Enrollment Infrastructure.............1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20
        szOID_AUTO_ENROLL_CTL_USAGE             1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.1
     Extension contain certificate type
        szOID_ENROLL_CERTTYPE_EXTENSION         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2
        szOID_ENROLLMENT_AGENT                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.1
        szOID_KP_SMARTCARD_LOGON                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2
        szOID_NT_PRINCIPAL_NAME                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3
        szOID_CERT_MANIFOLD                     1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.3

Microsoft CertSrv Infrastructure................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21
     CertSrv (with associated encoders/decoders)
        szOID_CERTSRV_CA_VERSION                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.1

     Contains the sha1 hash of the previous version of the CA certificate.
        szOID_CERTSRV_PREVIOUS_CERT_HASH        1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.2

     Delta CRLs only. Contains the base CRL Number of the corresponding base CRL.
        szOID_CRL_VIRTUAL_BASE                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.3

     Contains the time when the next CRL is expected to be published. This may be sooner than the CRL's NextUpdate field.
        szOID_CRL_NEXT_PUBLISH                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.4

     Enhanced Key Usage for CA encryption certificate
        szOID_KP_CA_EXCHANGE                    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.5

     Enhanced Key Usage for key recovery agent certificate
        szOID_KP_KEY_RECOVERY_AGENT             1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.6

     Certificate template extension (v2)
        szOID_CERTIFICATE_TEMPLATE              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7

     The root oid for all enterprise specific oids
        szOID_ENTERPRISE_OID_ROOT               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8

     Dummy signing Subject RDN
        szOID_RDN_DUMMY_SIGNER                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.9

     Application Policies extension -- same encoding as szOID_CERT_POLICIES
        szOID_APPLICATION_CERT_POLICIES         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10

     Application Policy Mappings -- same encoding as szOID_POLICY_MAPPINGS
        szOID_APPLICATION_POLICY_MAPPINGS       1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.11

     Application Policy Constraints -- same encoding as szOID_POLICY_CONSTRAINTS
        szOID_APPLICATION_POLICY_CONSTRAINTS    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.12

        szOID_ARCHIVED_KEY_ATTR                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.13   
        szOID_CRL_SELF_CDP                      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.14   

     Requires all certificates below the root to have a non-empty intersecting issuance certificate policy usage.
        szOID_REQUIRE_CERT_CHAIN_POLICY         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.15   
        szOID_ARCHIVED_KEY_CERT_HASH            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.16   
        szOID_ISSUED_CERT_HASH                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.17   

     Enhanced key usage for DS email replication
        szOID_DS_EMAIL_REPLICATION              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.19    

        szOID_REQUEST_CLIENT_INFO               1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.20   
        szOID_ENCRYPTED_KEY_HASH                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.21   
        szOID_CERTSRV_CROSSCA_VERSION           1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.22        

Microsoft Directory Service.....................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.25
        szOID_NTDS_REPLICATION                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.25.1

IIS.............................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.30
        szOID_IIS_VIRTUAL_SERVER                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.30.1

Microsoft WWOps BizExt..........................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.43


Microsoft Peer Networking.......................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44
     Subtrees for genaral use including pnrp, IM, and grouping
        szOID_PEERNET_GENERAL
        szOID_PEERNET_PNRP                      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.1
        szOID_PEERNET_IDENTITY                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.2
        szOID_PEERNET_GROUPING                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3

     Property that contains the type of the certificate (GMC, GRC, etc.)
        szOID_PEERNET_CERT_TYPE                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.0.1

     Type of the value in the 'other' name: peer name
        szOID_PEERNET_PEERNAME                  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.0.2

     Type : classifier
        szOID_PEERNET_CLASSIFIER                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.0.3

     Property containing the version of the certificate
        szOID_PEERNET_CERT_VERSION              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.0.4

     PNRP specific properties
        szOID_PEERNET_PNRP_ADDRESS              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.1.1
        szOID_PEERNET_PNRP_FLAGS                1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.1.2
        szOID_PEERNET_PNRP_PAYLOAD              1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.1.3
        szOID_PEERNET_PNRP_ID                   1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.1.4

     Identity flags, placeholder
        szOID_PEERNET_IDENTITY_FLAGS            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.2.2

     Peer name of the group
        szOID_PEERNET_GROUPING_PEERNAME         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3.1

     Group flags: placeholder
        szOID_PEERNET_GROUPING_FLAGS            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3.2

     List of roles in the GMC
        szOID_PEERNET_GROUPING_ROLES            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3.3

     List of classifiers in the GMC
        szOID_PEERNET_GROUPING_CLASSIFIERS      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3.5

Mobile Devices Code Signing.....................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.45

CAPICOM.........................................1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88
     Reserved for CAPICOM.
        szOID_CAPICOM                           1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88      

     CAPICOM version
        szOID_CAPICOM_VERSION                   1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.1

     CAPICOM attribute
        szOID_CAPICOM_ATTRIBUTE                 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2

     Document type attribute   
        szOID_CAPICOM_DOCUMENT_NAME             1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2.1

     Document description attribute
        szOID_CAPICOM_DOCUMENT_DESCRIPTION      1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2.2

     CAPICOM encrypted data message.
        szOID_CAPICOM_ENCRYPTED_DATA            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.3

     CAPICOM content of encrypted data.
        szOID_CAPICOM_ENCRYPTED_CONTENT         1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.3.1
```

Comment: there's a copy of the page at https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/287547